# What type of database for storing ML experiments

Tags: database, experimental-design, nosql

So I'm thinking to write some small piece of software, which to run/execute ML experiments on a cluster or arbitrary abstracted executor and then save them such that I can view them in real time efficiently. The executor software will have access for writing to the database and will push metrics live. Now, I have not worked too much with databases, thus I'm not sure what is the correct approach for this. Here is a description of what the system should store:

Each experiment will consist of a single piece of code/archive of code such that it can be executed on the remote machine. For now we will assume allow dependencies and etc are installed there. The code will accept command line arguments. The experiment also will consists of a YAML scheme defining the command line arguments. In the code byitself will specify what will be logged in (e.g. I will provide a library in the language for registering channels). Now in terms of logging, you can log numerical values, arrays, text, etc so quite a few types. Each channel will be allowed a single specification (e.g. 2 columns, first int iteration, second float error). The code will also provide special copy of parameters at the end of the experiments.

When one submit an experiments, it will need to provide its unique group name + parameters for execution. This will launch the experiment and log everything.

Implementing this for me is easiest to do with a flat file system. Each project will have a unique name. Each new experiment gets a unique id and folder inside the project. I can store the code there. Each channel gets a file, which for simplicity can be an csv delimeter, with a special schema file describing what type of values are stored there so I can load them there. The final parameters can also be copied in the folder.

However, because of the variety of ways I can do this, and the fact that this might require a separate "table" for each experiment, I have no idea if this is possible in any database systems? Additionally, maybe I'm overseeing something very obvious or maybe not, if  you had any experience with this any suggestions/advices are most welcome. The main goal is at the end to be able to serve this to a web interface. Maybe noSQL could accommodate this maybe not (I don't know exactly how those work)?

Answer (score 0):

The data for ML primarily would be unstructured data. That kind of data will not naturally fit into a RDBMS. Essentially a document database like mongodb is far better suited....for such cases.